# How to prove the Minkowski inequality (triangular) using Hölder and Cauchy-Schwarz for every space?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How to prove the Minkowski inequality (triangular) using Hölder and Cauchy-Schwarz for every space?

$||f+g||_p\leq ||f||_p+||g||_p$

for 
$1\leq p \leq \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: replace $g$ by $tg$ and consider that
$$||f+g||_p-||f||_p=\int_0^1\frac d{dt}||f+tg||_p$$
and
$$
||f||_p+||g||_p-||f||_p=\int_0^1\frac d{dt}(||f||_p+t||g||_p)
$$
to prove
$$
\frac d{dt}||f+tg||_p\le\frac d{dt}(||f||_p+t||g||_p)
$$

Comment: Is there a way w/o using integrals?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $1<p<  \infty $, and let $f,g \in L^p$, we have:
$$|f+g|^p \leq (|f|+|g|)^2 \leq 2^p (|f|^p+|g|^p)$$
Consequently, $f+g \in L^p$. On the other hand,
$$||f+g||_{p}^p = \int |f+g|^{p-1} |f+g| \leq   \int |f+g|^{p-1}|f| + \int |f+g|^{p-1}|g| $$
But $|f+g|^{p-1} \in L^{p'}$, and by Hölder's inq we obtain
$$   ||f+g||_{p}^{p}\leq ||f+g||_{p}^{p-1}(||f||_{p}+||g||_{p})  $$
i.e., $||f+g||_{p} \leq ||f||_{p} +||g||_{p}$

I am sure you can prove cases $p=1, p=\infty$, otherwise just comment.